# Integration Testing Ember: How to use Ember.run with ember-auth

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-testing

Trying to get tests running with QUnit and Teaspoon.  I have the following test:

```
test("Employee signs in", function(){
  visit("/").then(function(){
    return fillIn("#email", "employee@example.com");
  }).then(function(){
    return fillIn("#password", "password");
  }).then(function(){
    return click("#button");
  }).then(function(){
    ok(find("span:contains('Some Text')").length, "Should see Some Text");
  });
});
```

However, when I run the test, I get this error:

```
You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in an Ember.run
```

My understand is that there is some asynchronous code in my app that needs to be wrapped in an Ember.run since the run-loop is disabled during testing.  I am using ember-auth and I believe the following bit of code is where the async is happening on sign-in:

```
  submit: function(event, view) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    App.Auth.signIn({
      data: {
        email:    this.get('email'),
        password: this.get('password'),
        remember: true, //this.get('remember')

      }
    });
  }
```

But I am unsure how to wrap this in an Ember.run and the things I have tried thus far do not work.  How do I wrap the async part of this code in an Ember.run so that I can execute the test?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap basically all the code in an ember run loop:

```
test("Employee signs in", function(){
  Ember.run(function(){
    visit("/").then(function(){
      return fillIn("#email", "employee@example.com");
    }).then(function(){
      return fillIn("#password", "password");
    }).then(function(){
      return click("#button");
    }).then(function(){
      ok(find("span:contains('Some Text')").length, "Should see Some Text");
    });
  });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Doing this didn't work, and I heard that you only want to wrap the code that is making the asynchronous request in Ember.run.  Maybe because we are using the ember-auth gem, I am using Ember.run at too high a level?

Answer (score 0):

[ember-auth](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com) dev here.

This doesn't achieve fully what you wanted, but I use two approaches when testing this in `ember-auth` itself (with [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/)).

First way is to use an API mock, as in [these specs](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth/blob/610724c94916b4f386ff0f51824f032436cf6ef3/spec/javascripts/request/jquery-spec.em#L89). Basically I turn the async call into a sync one, and have the mock framework return the response immediately for `ember-auth` to consume.

```
beforeEach ->
  $.mockjax
    url: '/foo'
    type: 'POST'
    status: 200
    # ...
  Em.run -> doSomething()

it 'is successful', ->
  expect(foo).toBe bar
```

(I used [jquery-mockjax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax) in the specs.)

Second way is to ignore what `ember-auth` does, and just test that you have called the expected public API correctly, as in [these specs](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth/blob/610724c94916b4f386ff0f51824f032436cf6ef3/spec/javascripts/module/rememberable-spec.em#L23).

```
beforeEach ->
  spy = sinon.collection.spy auth, 'signIn'

it 'is successful', ->
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/* something */)
```

Hope this helps.